# Errors building GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, compile

I am trying to build grass-8.3.0 on a Debian Linux system. The configuration portion has only one flag:

```
--without-pdal
```

because Debian 12 does not have that package. The compilation finishes with:

```
Errors in:
/home/me/grass-8.3.0/db/drivers/dbf  
/home/me/grass-8.3.0/raster
```

When I run make in the 'dbf' directory, I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /home/me/grass-8.3.0/dist.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libgrass_sqlp.8.3.so: undefined reference to `yyerror'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/me/grass-8.3.0/dist.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/libgrass_sqlp.8.3.so: undefined reference to `yylex'
```

When I run make in the 'raster' directory, I get:

```
/usr/bin/ld: OBJ.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mapcalc.tab.o: in function `yyparse':
/home/me/grass-8.3.0/raster/r.mapcalc/mapcalc.tab.c:1138: undefined reference to `yylex'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/me/grass-8.3.0/raster/r.mapcalc/mapcalc.tab.c:1965: undefined reference to `yylex'
/usr/bin/ld: OBJ.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mapcalc.tab.o: in function `parse_string':
/home/me/grass-8.3.0/raster/r.mapcalc/mapcalc.y:270: undefined reference to `initialize_scanner_string'
/usr/bin/ld: OBJ.x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/mapcalc.tab.o: in function `parse_stream':
/home/me/grass-8.3.0/raster/r.mapcalc/mapcalc.y:278: undefined reference to `initialize_scanner_stream'
```

I have flex installed. What is the fix for these issues?

Comment: Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 2):

I simply had to upgrade flex to version 2.6.4.  Now grass-8.3.0 compiles perfectly.